# Can chrome extensions modify the horizontal tabs menu on top of the web browser?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The horizontal tabs menu is the bar on top of the web browser that I can click on to jump to different tabs.

For example, can I make a chrome extension that highlights a tab in the tabs bar for 5 seconds before closing it?

Answer (score 1):

Try [`chrome.tabs.highlight`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-highlight):

> highlight
>   chrome.tabs.highlight(object highlightInfo, function callback)
>
> Since Chrome 16.
>
> Highlights the given tabs.